# regex working in MATCH_RECOGNIZE function

Tags: sql, oracle

Have a below data set

```
loginName   emp_name    dept_id     dept_name                   startDate   endDate      
KK          KKLeo       5652        POLO Business – Tech        18-09-17    19-09-17
KK          KKLeo       5652        POLO Business – Tech        19-09-17    28-09-17
KK          KKLeo       5652        POLO Business – Tech        28-09-17    09-11-17
KK          KKLeo       5647        POLO Business               09-11-17    15-03-19
KK          KKLeo       5647        POLO Business               15-03-19    16-04-19
KK          KKLeo       5649        POLO Buss-Fixed Sales Mkt   16-04-19    03-05-19
KK          KKLeo       5649        POLO Buss-Fixed Sales Mkt   03-05-19    11-10-19
KK          KKLeo       5649        POLO Buss-Fixed Sales Mkt   11-10-19    22-07-20
KK          KKLeo       5649        POLO Buss-Fixed Sales Mkt   22-07-20    26-08-20
KK          KKLeo       5652        POLO Business – Tech        26-08-20    17-02-21
KK          KKLeo       5652        POLO Business – Tech        17-02-21    19-02-21
KK          KKLeo       5652        POLO Business – Tech        19-02-21    null
```

when I run this query

```
SELECT *
FROM   empdepthist
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY login_name
  ORDER BY startdate
  MEASURES
    (emp_name) AS emp_name,
    (dept_id) AS dept_id,
    (dept_name) AS dept_name,
    (startDate) AS startdate,
    (endDate) AS enddate 
  PATTERN (same_dept)
  DEFINE same_dept AS FIRST(dept_id) = dept_id
)
```

In output, I get `all` records, but when I use `same_dept+` instead `same_dept`, it give me only `4` records in output

```
KK          KKLeo       5652        POLO Business – Tech        28-09-17    09-11-17
KK          KKLeo       5647        POLO Business               15-03-19    16-04-19
KK          KKLeo       5649        POLO Buss-Fixed Sales Mkt   22-07-20    26-08-20
KK          KKLeo       5652        POLO Business – Tech        19-02-21    null
```

May Know please how this is behaving like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour is `ONE ROW PER MATCH`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   empdepthist
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY login_name
  ORDER BY startdate
  MEASURES
    (emp_name) AS emp_name,
    (dept_id) AS dept_id,
    (dept_name) AS dept_name,
    (startDate) AS startdate,
    (endDate) AS enddate 
  ONE ROW PER MATCH        -- default behaviour
  PATTERN (same_dept)
  DEFINE same_dept AS FIRST(dept_id) = dept_id
)
```

Your pattern `same_dept` will only match a single row. When you change the pattern to `same_dept+` it can match multiple rows; however, you have not told it that you want `ALL ROWS PER MATCH` so it is only giving you the default `ONE ROW PER MATCH`. If you do not want the default then you need to state that in the query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   empdepthist
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY login_name
  ORDER BY startdate
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH        -- not the default behaviour
  PATTERN (same_dept+)
  DEFINE same_dept AS FIRST(dept_id) = dept_id
)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=997b52feba98ef37abf83865ec517738)*

Comment: but why its giving all records while using PATTERN (same_dept) with default ONE ROW PER MATCH ?

Comment: As I said in the answer "Your pattern `same_dept` will only match a single row." ... as a corollary to that, every row has the same `dept_id` as itself so every row is matched.

Comment: any reason removing measures while using ALL ROWS PER MATCH ?

Comment: It is not needed for your query as it will return all the columns from the input when you use `ALL ROWS PER MATCH`. Using `ONE ROW PER MATCH` will only return the columns in the `PARTITION BY` clause so you need to explicitly state that you need the other columns, if you require them. You can re-add the `MEASURES` clause if you want to add additional columns using `MATCH_NUMBER()`, `CLASSIFIER()`, `FIRST`, `LAST`, other aggregation functions, etc.

Comment: understood and one ore thing, as we can see there is only partition is there in data for loginname, but when we use DEFINE same_dept AS FIRST(dept_id) = dept_id, does it create different groups too in partition ? I mean records falls (iterating one by one from partition) in one specific group until its dept_id is changed..correct ?

Comment: @Kate Yes [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=be80753d6aab6ad4dd35f297a85bf02e).